# How to Track Whom Up voted your Question or Answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a special privileges allocated to view whom up voted your answer or question. Just curios to know whether it is completely confidential or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible under normal circumstances to track this, by design. Voting is intended to be anonymous. Under certain circumstances, you may be able to guess who the voter is, but there's no built-in way in the software for anyone other than a developer to tell who voted on your posts, and even for developers it isn't easy. You can, however, check who favorited your question via [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/205985/who-favorited-me).

Moderators can look for trends in voting to detect serial voting, which is not allowed. In addition, some badges (and [your profile page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/9260/sarenya)) reveal some very coarse information about your own voting preferences. There's no way for a user here to reconstruct who voted for them solely based on that, and that is very much intended.

Comment: Yes, note that under normal circumstances, even mods cannot see who votes for what.